# Java Read File/Scanner

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java, and I am struggling to get this code to work. I am trying to read in a CSV file, and then use that data to calculate the averages, and then return a summary of the highest lowest and average of the averages.

The input looks like this:

> Alicia Marks,89,90,100,95,75,85,94,100,90,92
>
> Bobby Ricks,98,79,87,79,9,98,7,19,98,78

Here's what the out put should look like (Numbers are not correct, example only):

> Alicia Marks 85.5 B
>
> Bobby Ricks 90.0 A-
>
> ...
>
> High 98.2
>
> Low 56.5
>
> Average 78.3333

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test x = new Test();
        x.high();
    }

    public void high()
    {
        File file2 = new File("scores.csv");
        try
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file2);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] value2 = line2.split(",");

                // Converts String Array into Double Array
                double[] score = new double[value2.length];
                for (int i = 1; i < value2.length; i++)
                {
                    score[i] = Double.parseDouble(value2[i]);
                }

                // Finds the sum and then the average, adds it to a array List
                ArrayList<Double> av;
                av = new ArrayList<Double>();
                double sumNum = 0.0;
                for (double i : score)
                {
                    sumNum += i;
                }
                double aver = sumNum / 10;
                av.add(aver);

                double max = 0, min = 100;
                for (int a = 0; a < av.size(); a++)
                {
                    double s = av.get(a);
                    max = Math.max(max, s);
                    min = Math.min(min, s);
                    aver += s;
                }

                System.out.println("High " + max + "");
                System.out.println("Low " + min + "");
                System.out.println("Average " + aver / av.size() + "");

            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem I am having is with the while loop, but I am not too sure. Any help in fixing this would be really appreciated.

Comment: You tell us your needs, you show us code, but you don't tell us what's wrong with your code making it very difficult for us to help you. Please tell us what is wrong with your code, how it's not behaving correctly.

Comment: Why you `av = new ArrayList<Double>();` on each iteration? Put this outside the `while` loop.

Comment: `Here's what the out put should look like` but what *does* it look like?

Comment: Is this question solved?

Answer (score 1):

You have one error in the function reading the grades. You should fix it in this way:

```
// Converts String Array into Double Array
double[] score = new double[value2.length - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < value2.length; i++) {
    score[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble(value2[i]);
}
```

As far I've understood, you want the max, min and the averages' mean of all the grades. Then your code should be like this:

```
package it.unitn.uvq.antonio.processor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test();
        x.high();
    }

    public void high() {
        File file2 = new File("/home/antonio/Scrivania/scores.csv");
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file2);
            ArrayList<Double> avgs = new ArrayList<>();
            double max = 0, min = 100;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] value2 = line2.split(",");

                // Converts String Array into Double Array
                double[] score = new double[value2.length - 1];
                for (int i = 1; i < value2.length; i++) {
                    score[i - 1] = Double.parseDouble(value2[i]);
                }

                // Finds the sum and then the average, adds it to a array List
                double sumNum = 0.0;
                for (double i : score) {
                    sumNum += i;
                    min = Math.min(min, i);
                    max = Math.max(max, i);
                }
                double avg = sumNum / 10;
                avgs.add(avg);

                System.out.println(avg);
            }
            scanner.close();
            double avgsSum = .0;
            for (double avg : avgs) {
                avgsSum += avg;
            }
            System.out.println("High " + max + "");
            System.out.println("Low " + min + "");
            System.out.println("Average " + avgsSum / avgs.size() + "");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the average for each student, and then the min and max and total average of those, you could do:

**Edit:** added an example of how you could do the number to character conversion. Notice: I don't know how you tell if it's a B- or D+ and etc.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test();
        x.high();
    }

    public void high() {
        // to format the scores
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        ArrayList<Double> averages = new ArrayList<Double>();

        File file2 = new File("scores.csv");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file2);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] values = line.split(",");

                // Converts String Array into Double Array
                double[] scoresPerPerson = new double[values.length];

                for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                    scoresPerPerson[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
                }

                // Finds the sum and then the average, adds it to a array List
                double sum = 0.0;

                for (double i : scoresPerPerson) {
                    sum += i;
                }

                double average = sum / values.length;
                averages.add(average);

                System.out.println(values[0] + ": " + df.format(average) + " "
                        + getCharGrade(average));

            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Computes the average and get the max min

        double max = 0;
        double min = 100;
        double totalAverage = 0;

        for (double average : averages) {
            if (average > max) {
                max = average;
            }
            if (average < min) {
                min = average;
            }
            totalAverage += average;
        }

        // Final step to get the general average
        totalAverage /= averages.size();

        // Print out the final general data
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("High : " + df.format(max));
        System.out.println("Low : " + df.format(min));
        System.out.println("Average : " + df.format(totalAverage));
    }

    private String getCharGrade(double average) {

        if (average >= 90) {
            return "A";
        } else if (average >= 80) {
            return "B";
        } else if (average >= 70) {
            return "C";
        } else if (average >= 60) {
            return "D";
        } else {
            return "F";
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Alicia Marks: 82,7 B
Bobby Ricks: 59,3 F

High : 82,7
Low : 59,3
Average : 71
```